# Trouble with Conditional Formatting Date + Other Conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm relatively new to Excel and have to stitch together something. I'm having some trouble with conditional formatting.

[image]

What I'd like to do is, for each line, type in the date of request. The hidden column is just the date of request +21 days. For the heading records rec'd, I have it elsewhere with 1 and 0, and then a custom cell view in which [=1}"Yes";[=0]"No". When the "hidden" column date is in the past, I'd like to conditionally format the date of request to appear in red.

I've tried something like this: =IF($F$3

Comment: Where's the rest of your formula you tried?

Comment: =IF+($F$3+21<(TODAY())*AND($H$3="No")

Comment: Try this formula `=AND($F$3+21<(TODAY(),$H$3="No")`

Comment: if only the hidden column matters select `A:E` conditional-formatting-formula: `=($C1<Now())*($C1>0)` (if C is the hidden column)

Answer (score 0):

> When the "hidden" column date is in the past, I'd like to conditionally format the date of request to appear in red

The hidden column is not required for conditional formatting as the calculation of 21 days can be done within the CF formula rule. Select `Date of Request` (assumed to be ColumnF) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=TODAY()>F1+21
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of red, OK, OK.

However you also mention `Records Rec'd?` column (presumably H) and if the above formatting is not to apply when the corresponding row contains "Yes" (on its own) in that column, change the above formula to:

```
 =AND(TODAY()>F1+21,H1<>"Yes")
```

The reference to columnH *might* be changeable to the source (`1`s or `0`s) that trigger the `Yes`, depending on how the `Yes` and `No` are derived.

For simplicity the formatting rule has been applied to the entire column. If a shorter range is required select from H3:Hn (where `n` is the highest row number in the range) and adjust the formula from F1 to F3 and from H1 to H3, or don't adjust but set another rule for the first three rows that applies no formatting but takes precedence, or specifically exclude the first three rows within the formula.

IF is not normally required within a CF formatting rule (because such formatting is *conditional*).